# Remove duplicates unsuccessful using duplicated or distinct

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I seem to have difficulty in removing duplicates using either the `duplicated` or `distinct` functions in `dplyr`. I don't know what the problem is but can anyone help? Here is a small part of the data as an example:

```
df <- data.frame(timestamp = c(1495115680.55608, 1495115680.58941, 
                             1495115680.62274), id = c("2017-05-18-145157833880", "2017-05-18-145157833880", 
                                                       "2017-05-18-145157833880"), condition = c("childchild", "childchild", 
                                                                                                 "childchild"))
```

Both these two functions fail to remove duplicates

```
df %>%
  filter(!duplicated(timestamp))

distinct(df, timestamp, .keep_all = TRUE)
   timestamp                      id  condition
1 1495115681 2017-05-18-145157833880 childchild
2 1495115681 2017-05-18-145157833880 childchild
3 1495115681 2017-05-18-145157833880 childchild
```

Comment: Your timestamps aren't identical., so they are all distinct.

Comment: If you only need 1-second accuracy, you can filter with `!duplicated(round(timestamp))`

Comment: @MelissaKey you are correct because `df$timestamp[1]==df$timestamp[2]` returns false but just by looking they are the same. So how can we tell?

Comment: I could tell by looking at the decimals in your example.  Obviously you wouldn't do that for a large data set, but it's usually a good place to start whenever you're dealing with numeric data.  And rounding (as suggested by @Brian) is a good fix if it's the cause & you don't need that level of accuracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to floating-point precision.
The timestamps are duplicate only to a certain point of decimal places.

One way to solve this is to round and then apply `filter()` or `distinct()`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(timestamp1 = round(timestamp, 0)) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(timestamp1)) %>% 
  select(-timestamp1)

 timestamp                      id  condition
1 1495115681 2017-05-18-145157833880 childchild
```